# How to wrap a function with multiple overloads in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to wrap a function to decorate it with some behaviour. I am able to create a function with multiple overloads, however even though the overloads' parameter types match those of the overloads of the wrapped function, I can't seem to get it to work without type guard functions, which seems silly.

[Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false#code/PTAEAEDsHsEkFsAOAbAlgY1QFwIKQJ4BcoAZgIbIDOApgFBb6LWgBi0ATvAMoCuARvGwAJMpAAmyau1ABeUAAoxZLGWJtOAEWVkAlLIB8oAG7RUY0ADJQAcgD6tyj2rX6jZgFlqlSmQDm1EXFJaTl5aiMsYk9vP2oAUSNqSCw9GUMTM0sbez5oPhcGJlA47AALKUCJKVlWDm5%20QSxK4NAAH1Bon39mqQBuWloSHkh0LFRoSFBS0Sr3MlRIBKSseVpQUGpJeGIhABV3ABl1eDit5YAaNamZ4LU63gFhG6laHUHh0fHJ6aDqOYWlslVutNtRtqA9odYCx2GR4PEzslLusflV2FEvF0As92K93iMxhNrr9-otEkCrqDwZCjnVTmDlm0IfsDtDYfD6fCkVdUbdapwHo0etJ2p1YsLXqAAN4AXwGQwJX1AqEoNLZcIRDKBVOIonwOmIVOVlGZUJhGs5jKlV3Y1CwPHYk2s6AmWGWGmg6B4XKw1mVkyp-Tl%20M%20RJVNOOlu1W11BANGy2xtNtM4Uaw0ptdodkwAhPJna73Z7vcs-QsE2CdEH5R9CZMVcdBU9fux5LypMQSlhyuxhfH29IVfz6o8mjiM%20tbfbHdkHE4y98cdWQ3XjWLuji2zjO2UKjj%20%20Oh%20vsS2J6Ap9nZ7l8v7iWjlwrQ4uSfMycsAEzAivUlmRxFYZE7z5RsGmbNE8UfVd21JQEsE-SkY2TdUOX-QCBwxGINxbCDayVaDX1g%20CQUQiM6X-Jk1XNFCtQAnlt2HJsx1PUVMXFHFJWtdZUBIBRwxZZDNR9MItj0CwrBVY9hS3FsdD0Tj1nPLMZ3wgFyRWKlziAqQqyuOViJoZUePkPjDj-GjhMrSxxMoEDRykgdZLPSclOfWYCLUiz4E0hz%20nWOUZSAA) is a TS Playground to illustrate my approach so far.

What I have is this:

```js
function handleMainEvent(
  elem: HTMLFormElement,
  handler: FormSubmitHandler
)
function handleMainEvent(
  elem: HTMLIFrameElement,
  handler: MessageHandler
)
function handleMainEvent(
  elem: HTMLFormElement | HTMLIFrameElement,
  handler: FormSubmitHandler | MessageHandler
) {}

function handleMainEvent2(
  elem: HTMLFormElement,
  handler: FormSubmitHandler
)
function handleMainEvent2(
  elem: HTMLIFrameElement,
  handler: MessageHandler
)
function handleMainEvent2(
  elem: HTMLFormElement | HTMLIFrameElement,
  handler: FormSubmitHandler | MessageHandler
) {
  if (isHTMLIFrameElement(elem) && isMessageHandler(handler)) {
    return handleMainEvent(elem, handler);
  }
  else if (isHTMLFormElement(elem) && isFormSubmitHandler(handler)) {
    return handleMainEvent(elem, handler);
  }
}
```

...but I would like to write something like this:

```js
function handleMainEvent2(
  elem: HTMLFormElement,
  handler: FormSubmitHandler
)
function handleMainEvent2(
  elem: HTMLIFrameElement,
  handler: MessageHandler
)
function handleMainEvent2(
  elem: HTMLFormElement | HTMLIFrameElement,
  handler: FormSubmitHandler | MessageHandler
) {
    return handleMainEvent(elem, handler);
  }
}
```

What is the most straightforward way to decorate a function with multiple overloads with arbitrary behaviour?

Comment: Overloads are intentionally more loosely typed in the implementation than in the call signatures, which means calling one from inside another one might warn. Inside your `handleMainEvent2` implementation, `elem` and `handler` are uncorrelated union types; the compiler has no idea that they are properly paired, and even being a union at all prevents calling `handleMainEvent` since neither call signature accepts unions.  My suggestion is either refactoring away from overloads are type assertions, as [here](//tsplay.dev/wEDYkW). Do either of those work for you? If so I'll write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz no it doesn't work for me, as I am trying to wrap a function from a dependency I don't control. Also the type signatures are a bit hairy.
The only other thing I thought of, is to wrap the overloaded function with 2 separate functions, 1 for each overload signature. Then "wrap" those with another function, which calls the correct wrapper based on a type guard.

Comment: So the ["just use type assertions" part](https://tsplay.dev/w2KgrN) at the bottom does *not* work for you?  That doesn't require you change anything about signatures

Comment: @jcalz yes that works.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do here; it's been months, after all.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer with any of my approaches above.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah I don't see where to go with this, besides the answer "no", which I would accept :D. In your provided example "as" is used to assert types that would be in some cases incorrect, something I would not do.
In my case the problem is complicated by return types also, since the argument type combinations are MECE, but in the body of the function with overloads TS can't infer when type combinations are exhausted, and still needs a fallthrough return statement or throw statement which won't be reached. So it seems either way some "code lies" must be introduced, which is a shame.